# Generic multiple parameter of same type

Tags: java, generics, multiparameter

I am trying to understand generics. In the below code getDuplicate() return type `PlaceHolder<X,X>` has same parameter X which compiles fine. But when I use the same parameter type in `MyClass<T,T>` it says "type variable T already defined". Can someone explain how it's possible with getDuplicate method?

```
class PlaceHolder<K,V> {
   public K k;
   public K v;

   public PlaceHolder(K k, K v){
       this.k = k;
       this.v = v;
   }

   public K get(){ return k;    }

   public static <X> PlaceHolder<X,X> getDuplicateHolder(X x){
        return new PlaceHolder<X,X>(x,x);
   }

}

class MyTest<T,T> {}
```

Comment: `MyTest<T,T>` has duplicate Type parameter, `T` was repeated, use `MyTest<T,U>` or anything else in place of second `T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `X` is declared once and used twice where `T` is being declared twice.

In methods, you can declare type parameters with `<>` after modifiers but before the return type.  Likewise, in classes and interfaces, you can declare type parameters after the class name but before any `implements` and/or `extends` clauses and before the class/interface body.

You may use these type parameters in the scope in which they're declared.  Declaring a return type of `PlaceHolder<X, X>` is using `X` twice, but declaring a class `MyText<T, T>` is attempting to declare `T` twice.

A variable-equivalent analogy would be declaring a variable and using it twice:

```
int x;
...
x + x
```

vs. attempting to declare two variables with the same name.

```
int t;
int t;
```

You just need to make sure you know when you're declaring a type parameter and when you're using an existing type parameter.